# Using Integration by Parts for Transpose of a Derivative

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, inner-products, transpose

In *Introduction to Linear Algebra: Fifth Edition* by Gilbert Strang, it supposes that we have a matrix $A$ such that it differentiates the elements in a vector $x$ via $Ax$. It then resolves to find the transpose of $A$. First it defines the inner product as

$$x^{T}y = (x,y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)y(t) dt \space\space\space (Eq \space 1)$$
Then:
$$(Ax,y) = (Ax)^T y = x^T A^T y = x^T(A^T y) = (x,A^Ty) \space\space\space (Eq \space 2)$$
It then gives the following:
3) $$(Ax,y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{dt}y(t) dt= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)(-\frac{dy}{dt}) dt = (x,A^T)y \space\space\space (Eq \space 3)$$

And then it states that

> **I hope you recognize integration by parts.** The derivative moves from the first function x(t) to the second function y(t). During that move, a minus sign appears. This tells us that **the transpose of the derivative is minus the derivative**

But I am confused by the "integration by parts". In order to do integration by parts for the second integral we would need:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{dt}y(t) dt = x(t)y(t)|^\infty_{-\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)(\frac{dy}{dt})dt = x(t)y(t)|^\infty_{-\infty} + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x(t)(-\frac{dy}{dt})dt$$

But to get $(Eq \space 3)$,$\space x(t)y(t)|^\infty_{-\infty}$ would need to be $0$. But how do we prove this? Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks.

Comment: There is some information missing here. What is the vector space here? However, I suspect that is a subset of integrable functions on the real line which means that those functions do approach $0$ as you move to (negative) infinity. It is similiar to series (or infinite sums), you might know that if a series converges, the sequence that is summed up has to converge to $0$.

Comment: I have to note, there are more conditions required for this to be the case, integrability is not enough, take a look at [this discussion](https://mathhelpforum.com/threads/do-integrable-functions-decay-to-zero.166482/) for some counter-examples and sufficient conditions.

Comment: @ManateePink thank you very much!